# Getting error while pushing a lightning component to salesforce org

Tags: salesforce, lwc

I am following a [trailhead guide](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/set-up-your-lightning-web-components-developer-tools/analyze-your-code-and-deploy-it-to-your-org?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components) and using `sfdx force:source:push` command to push my lightning component after I have done creating and updating my lwc component.

I am getting below error while pushing

```
MissingMessageError: Missing message source_push:commandDescription for locale en_US.
```

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing the CLI.

Comment: I did try it installing and re installing again, also I tried to add a default org. It gives me the same error.